# SVG Filter Transition in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-transitions, svg-filters

I'm attempting to transition an image from a 50% grey scale filter to its filterless state on hover.

The transition doesn't work in firefox however. Is it possible to get the transition running in firefox using only css?

```
img {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'0.5\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray alpha(opacity=50); /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
    -moz-transition: all .6s ease; 
    -ms-transition: all .6s ease; 
    transition: all .6s ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
}
img:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Safari 5 or below too. How to add Safari 5 support ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the standard filter syntax is a url it's not amenable to transitioning. Gecko would have to implement the [shorthands](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html#ShorthandEquivalents) part of the under construction [Filter Effects](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html) specification for this to work.

In the meantime you could do this using SVG animation but not via CSS only.