# SVG filters, transitioning in Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-transitions, svg-filters

I'm working on a webpage where if you hover over an image, it'll desaturate. It works in Chrome and IE. However, I can't get the transition to work in FF and it doesn't desaturate at all in Opera.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>      
<style type="text/css">
    img:hover {         
        filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'0.0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox */
        filter: gray; /* IE */
        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit */}

    img {           
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(0);
        -o-filter: grayscale(0);
        filter: none;
        filter: grayscale(0);}

    img.transition {
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* FF */
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Opera 10.5 */
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Webkit */
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;}
</style>
</head>

<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://www.wallpapershd.biz/wallpapers/2012/12/Cardinal-Bird-1024x1280.jpg" width="500" class="transition" />
</body>
</html>
```

I've seen similar questions but I'm kind of a beginner, so the answers were a little abstract; you don't have to provide me with the code yourself, but point me to a somewhat detailed answer that I can understand. If anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look like this is possible in Firefox. Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757420/svg-filter-transition-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use a simple color transition from red to grey?